# testOptions setting is ignored when redefining the test task

Tags: testing, sbt

I have a subproject named `servision` with 2 tests configs:

- ti
- test

Here is my project config:

```
val beforeTest := taskKey[Unit]("Before test")

val ti = config("ti") extend (Test)
lazy val servision = project
    .configs(regresion, ti)
    .settings(
        inConfig(ti)(Defaults.testTasks) ++
            Seq(
                testOptions in test := Seq(Tests.Filter(!_.startsWith("ti.")})),
                testOptions in ti := Seq(Tests.Filter(_.startsWith("ti.")})),
                test in ti := {
                   Def.sequential(beforeTest, test in ti).value
                   afterTest()
                }
            )
        )
```

I've discovered, that if I redefine `ti:test`, then `ti:testOptions` are fully ignored, and `test:testOptions` are used instead.

If I comment out the redefinition, then `ti:testOptions` are used.

I think this is rather a bug in SBT, that a misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround.

In order to invoke some code before and after a tests, the `testsListener` can be used:

```
class TestsListenerBase extends TestsListener {
    override def doInit() {}

    override def doComplete(finalResult: TestResult.Value) {}

    override def testEvent(event: TestEvent) {}

    override def endGroup(name: String, t: Throwable) {}

    override def endGroup(name: String, result: TestResult.Value) {}

    override def startGroup(name: String) {}
}

def beforeTest() { .... } 
def afterTest() { .... } 

testListeners in ti += {
   new TestsListenerBase {
    override def doInit() {
             beforeTest()
        }

    override def doComplete(finalResult: TestResult.Value) {}
              afterTest()
        }
}
```

The main inconvenience of this solution, is that `beforeTest` and `afterTest` cannot be tasks, it must be converted into functions.  Otherwise, it cannot be controlled when it will be invoked.  Settings can be used as arguments to these functions.